# Ferramenta FREE para Wireframe

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

Dentre as várias ferramentas encontradas ao se pesquisar a respeito, alguém poderia dar indicação de uma boa ferramenta FREE para a criação de wireframe? O foco e desenvolvimento de sistema para web.

Observe que não busco a melhor, mas sim a indicação de quem já utilizou e pode recomendar.

O objetivo é de o cliente ver na folha de papel impressa e ter uma boa ideia de como a tela ficará depois de finalizada.

Agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Anderson, wireframe de alta fidelidade ou baixa? Para apresentação para cliente? Para testes de Experiência do usuário? Qual o motivo de fazer um wireframe?

Comment: Apresentação para cliente. O objetivo é que o cliente tenha conhecimento sobre o posicionamento dos dados, botões, layout, etc... Baixa fidelidade seria para o caso.

Comment: Seria Wireframe mesmo, ou um protótipo funcional? Ou seja, que tenha interação com o seu protótipo.

Comment: O mais simples. Apenas para o cliente ver na folha de papel impressa e ter uma boa ideia de como a tela ficará depois de finalizada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguem algumas opções:

- http://iplotz.com/ (Free até $79)
- http://pencil.evolus.vn/Default.html (Free)
- https://www.gliffy.com/ (Free até $9,95 por mês)
- http://www.mockflow.com/ (Free até $69 por ano)
- http://framebox.org/ (Free)
- http://iphonemockup.lkmc.ch/ (Free)

São considerados uns dos melhores.